# Manga about a girl who feeds a wolf boy friend?

Tags: story-identification, manga

The story is set in a fantasy world. The wolf boy is well attuned to nature and has been selected serve as a guardian, but begins a romantic relationship with the girl who always feeds him.

Comment: This question is very terse and could be greatly improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please do look at the linked suggestions; in particular can you tell us where and when you read this?

Comment: similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_Children ?